# Setting robot orientation

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I have 2 robots erratic robots in gazebo and I want them to have approximately the same orientation. I am trying following piece of code but it doesn't seem to have any effect on my robot's rotation.

```
tf::TransformListener listener;
    tf::StampedTransform transform;
    try {

        listener.waitForTransform("/odom", "/base_link", ros::Time(0),
                ros::Duration(3.0));
        listener.lookupTransform("/odom", "/base_link", ros::Time(0),
                transform);
    } catch (tf::TransformException ex) {
        ROS_ERROR("%s", ex.what());
    }

    tf::Quaternion rotation;
    rotation.setValue(robot2.orientation.x, robot2.orientation.y, robot2.orientation.z);
    transform.setRotation(rotation);
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/139036/setting-robot-orientation/) by [SpiderRico](https://answers.ros.org/users/10046/spiderrico/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2014-03-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jbinney](https://answers.ros.org/users/3292/jbinney/) on 2014-03-12**:
What do you mean "doesn't seem to be working"? Does it give a compilation error? Does the pose end up in the wrong place? How are you sending these transforms to gazebo?

**Comment by [SpiderRico](https://answers.ros.org/users/10046/spiderrico/) on 2014-03-12**:
Updated my question. Hope it's more clear now.

**Comment by [atp](https://answers.ros.org/users/5347/atp/) on 2014-03-12**:
I think that you have to broadcast the transform again. Have a look at the "Writing a tf broadcaster" tutorial.

**Comment by [SpiderRico](https://answers.ros.org/users/10046/spiderrico/) on 2014-03-12**:
@atp How did I miss that! It helped me a lot. If you  add this as  an answer, I'll accept it mate. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As atp suggested following [this](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20broadcaster%20(C%2B%2B)) tutorial solved my problem:

---

Originally posted by [SpiderRico](https://answers.ros.org/users/10046/spiderrico/) with karma: 35 on 2014-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0